# Why Poltergeist driver can NOT find some elements that are successfully found by Capybara (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, find, capybara, element, poltergeist

I've written set of TC using Capybara. All the tests are successfully run and no issues arise. Driver is defined as following:

```
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
```

But when I am trying to run the same TC using Capybara Poltergeist driver - I face with the problem that some elements can not be found by Poltergeist. For instance Poltergeist can not find such xpath:

```
"//div[./ul[@class='pricing-plan list-unstyled']/li[contains(., 'Basic')]]//li/a[contains(., 'Get Started')]"
```

Driver is defined as following:

```
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
  Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
  Capybara.current_driver = :poltergeist

  Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
    Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app,
                                      :phantomjs => File.join("E:/Programming/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/phantomjs.exe"),
                                      :js_errors => false,
                                      :phantomjs_options => ['--ignore-ssl-errors=yes'],
                                      :phantomjs_logger => File.open("F:/Programming/VLoop/Project/03.06.216/webapp/webapp/log/test_phantomjs.log", 'w+')
    )
  end
```

The question is why there is difference between Capybara and Poltergeist drivers and how to handle this issue of impossibility to find some elements by Poltergeist driver?

Comment: Both the selenium driver and poltergeist driver should find the same elements. if there is an issue we would need to see the HTML and CSS applied to it to try and figure out why poltergeist isn't finding the element. One potential issue could be if the initial window size is smaller and CSS is making the element non-visible in a smaller window.  Another potential issue could be if the element is created by JS and you're getting a JS error on poltergeist, but you're squelching those errors so you don't see it.

Comment: Then could you please suggest how I can make Poltergeist driver in full screen mode. Also it would be useful to know how to scroll down till desired element will be found.

Comment: Created an answer with how to change the default poltergeist screen size, since it's headless it doesn't really have a concept of full screen

Comment: sorry did you solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

Try adjusting the window size used by poltergeist/phantomjs by passing the window_size option to the driver when registering with a size large enough to display your page

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, :phantomjs => File.join("E:/Programming/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/phantomjs.exe"),
                                  :js_errors => false,
                                  :window_size => [1300,2000], #set whatever size you need here 
                                  :phantomjs_options => ['--ignore-ssl-errors=yes'],
                                  :phantomjs_logger => File.open("F:/Programming/VLoop/Project/03.06.216/webapp/webapp/log/test_phantomjs.log", 'w+')
  )
end
```

Making the page larger could mean elements that would have been hidden because they overflowed their containing elements may be visible with a larger page.  This isn't necessarily something you could fix by scrolling the page (the driver automatically scrolls the page if it needs to/can) since it depends on how/why the element is getting hidden which no one knows without seeing your actual HTML and CSS.

Comment: I've added ":window_size => [1300,2000],:window_size => [1300,2000]," line as you suggested (I tried to use differend definitions of screen, even up to 500000, 50000), but still see 
Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find xpath "//div[./ul[@class='pricing-plan list-unstyled']/li[contains(., 'Basic')]]//li/a[contains(., 'Get Started')]"

Comment: Did you try js_errors: true to make sure you're not having errors? If you have then there's no way to diagnose it without the page HTML and CSS

Comment: Also, is there any chance the Element is occluded in any way? Would need to perform some action to make it visible to a User in actual usage? PhantomJS needs it to be completely visible to be clickable, with the intention of really mimicking possible behaviors (and Capybara recently has switched to doing that as well).

Comment: I do not know how to handle this issue. I do not see any problems with the element. There is zip file with saved page. Particularly I need to make visible for Poltergeist each "Get Started" button: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1gsE8ME_RGpOHl3bk1DZ2xTcVE

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue writing feature specs with capybara + phantomJS (v2.1.1). Inspected elements were rendered properly in browser but phatomJS used to report an issue(copied below) which says that the bounds of inspected element were going out of window size with window_size set to [1600, 3000]

```
Capybara::Poltergeist::MouseEventFailed:
    Firing a click at co-ordinates [5789, 378] failed. Poltergeist detected another element with CSS selector '' at this position. It may be overlapping the element you are trying to interact with. If you don't care about overlapping elements, try using node.trigger('click').
```

On further investigation I figured out that phantomJS doesn't support css3 flexible box. I was using following css property to arrange boxes as shown in the picture below (rendered in chrome)

```css
.info-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

[image: css3 flexbox layout]

But looking at the error reported in my specs it seems that phantomJS was not able to stack the boxes properly and instead the boxes were placed horizontally next to each other. Sergey Kay: the google drive folder shared by you also has this css property *.event-table{display:flex;flex-flow:column}*

So to fix it I added the following js file to be included in the page with capybara tests. Here I've overridden the css class display property to use *display: table-cell* instead of *flex* and saved at following path **spec/override-flex-display.js**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var styleElement = document.createElement('style');
  styleElement.type = 'text/css';
  styleElement.innerHTML = '.info-wrapper { display: table-cell; }';
  document.head.appendChild(styleElement);
};
```

And included the js file above in **capybara.rb** configuration so it gets loaded in the html page when phantomjs tries to render it.

```ruby
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(
    app,
    js_errors: true,
    extensions: %w[
      ./spec/override-flex-display.js
    ],
    ....
  )
end
```

With the above change the inspected elements were found by Capybara::Poltergeist within the window size and specs got green.